# Stream analytics parse json, same key can be array or not

Tags: json, azure-stream-analytics

A XML is converted to JSON and sent to an EventHub and then a Stream Analytics process it.
The problem is when XML uses the same tags name it gets converted to a list on the JSON side, but when there is only one tag is not converted to a list. So the same tag can be an array or not.

Ex:
I can receive either:

```
{
  "k1": 123,
  "k2": {
    "l1": 2,
    "l2": 12
  }
}
```

or:

```
{
  "k1": 123,
  "k2": [
    {
      "l1": 2,
      "l2": 12
    },
    {
      "l1": 3,
      "l2": 34
    }
  ]
}
```

I can easily deal with the first scenario and the second scenario independently, but I don't know how to deal with both at the same time, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. If you know how to deal with each of the cases individually, I will just suggest an idea of how you can make the distinction between these two cases, before you treat them individually.

Essentially, the idea is to check if the field is an array. What I did was, I wrote a UDF function in javascript that returns "true"/"false", if the passed object is an array:

```
function UDFSample(arg1) {
    'use strict';
    var isArray = Array.isArray(arg1);
    return isArray.toString();
}
```

here is how you can use this in the group query:

```
with test as (SELECT Document from input where UDF.IsArray(k2) = 'true')
```

now "test" contains items that you can treat as an array. The same you can do for the case where k2 is just an object.